# Send Data on Client Socket without Client Requesting for it C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I want to Design Socket Server with Multiple Socket Client, in which once the Client gets connected to Server, server should start sending data to client and client must receive the data, and when Client gets disconnected server should stop sending data to that client. Can anyone suggest the method to achieve the above task in C#.

Comment: What have you tried to far? It could help people answering your question if you show your progress and where you get stuck.

Comment: I have implemented a Socket Server and Client where Client requests for data and server sends the response. But the solution i needed was once the client gets connected to server, server should start sending the responses of Data which client would require, here the data on server changes continuously which client should receive without requesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like pretty standard socket work to be honest. TCP sockets are simply a pair of streams (one in each direction). Either end can send data to the other *at any time*. Raw sockets are not request / response, although obviously request / response can be written on top of a socket. But so can ad-hoc messages in either direction.

So basically: just use a socket, and when the server wants to send something: *send it*. That's all there is. Broken sockets are detectable if you are writing to the socket, so the server will find out about the disconnect *either* via the regular socket-closed mechanism, or by getting an error message when sending.

Comment: Implement [handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking) via periodic `"Are you there"` -> `"I am still here"` messaging in any/both directions to detect disconnection sooner (which doesn't not necessary will be a socket disconnection).

Comment: thanks for reply, I have followed your suggestion of using Send method in a loop to send data continuously to the socket connected , but here i am facing delay issue because the messages are sent over a socket every 70 milliseconds and the delay goes on increasing after every message sent. Please suggest a way to optimize or any other method to achieve the task.